# Transfer files to Rackspace Cloud Files

Tags: php, upload, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I am working on getting all my client files moved from VPS server to Rackspace Cloud Files. Since there is about 2 GB to be transferred, I am looking for a good tool to perform the task.

One way to get this done would be to use Rackspace API and write a script to read from the location and create/upload files to Rackspace Cloud.The problem being that the script times out, plus this does not seem like a browser task.

Is there a tool / script which could be used to 'read' from a particular local/remote folder and create a container with the same folder name and transfer files from the folder to relevant container.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

It's not browser task, you have to run the script in CLI.But if you have no access to CLI, then just add those 2 lines in the beginning of the script:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort();
```

Another solution is to move files in chunks (for example 5 files per run), performing a redirect to the same script after each upload

Answer (score 0):

Try the Enterprise Cloud Backup Tools from SMEStorage.com Its on their Cloud Tools page [here](http://www.smestorage.com/?p=static&page=clients_and_tools#Windows).

I use this with RackSpace UK but it also supports RackSpace US.